# associated protocol conformance error swift 2.0

Tags: generics, swift2, swift-protocols

I am aware of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30033138/testing-protocol-conformance-with-associated-types) which presents the same problem as me, but is unanswered and old, so i thought id refresh it here.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play
import UIKit

protocol BaseViewModel { }

protocol SomeCellViewModelInterface : BaseViewModel { }
protocol AnotherCellViewModelInterface : BaseViewModel { }

protocol BaseCell {

    typealias T
    func configure(viewmodel: T)
}

//

class someCell : UIView, BaseCell {
    typealias T = SomeCellViewModelInterface
    func configure(viewmodel: T) {
        // awesome
    }
}

class someOtherCell : UIView, BaseCell {
    typealias T = AnotherCellViewModelInterface
    func configure(viewmodel: T) {
        // do stuff
    }
}


// the concrete implementations of viewmodels and actually using this UI is ultimatley in another .framework

class ConcreteSomeCellVM : SomeCellViewModelInterface { }
class ConcreteAnotherCellVM : AnotherCellViewModelInterface { }

var viewModel = ConcreteSomeCellVM()

let views: [UIView] = [someCell(), someOtherCell(), UIView()]
```

This is a rudimentary example of what I need but it illustrates the point

```
for v in views {

    // A
    if let cell = v as? someCell {
        cell.configure(viewModel)
    }

    // B
    if let cell = v as? BaseCell {
        cell.configure(viewModel)
    }  
}
```

Block A works, but needs to know the concrete cell class, so if i have a list of many different cells, some that I do not know the concrete type of this won't work.

Block B throws this error:

> error: protocol 'BaseCell' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Is there a way that Block B can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way that Block B can be achieved?

I don't think so. Pretend you are the compiler and think how you would create the code for `configure` in BaseCell.

- What type is T?
- How would you call `configure` on an instance of `BaseCell` knowing that it might really be a `someCell` or a `someOtherCell` each of which restricts the parameter to a different type? For instance

  ```
  func doSomethingWithACell(foo: BaseCell)
  {
      foo.configure(??? what can you put here?)
  }
  ```

To achieve what you really want, I think you need to get rid of the type alias and make the declaration like this:

```
protocol BaseCell {
    func configure(viewmodel: BaseViewModel)
}
```

In each of your classes, you would them need to handle the case where `viewModel` is not of the correct type.

Comment: yeah, the more i look at this, the more I think it is not possible in swift, if only you could have generic interfaces `protocol Something<T>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting an update of what I came up with so far, a kind of answer, whilst it is not ideal I have changed the configure method to look like this:
`func configure<T where T : BaseViewModel>(viewmodel: T)`

so that when i configure these views, I don't have to know the concrete class for each:

```
 for v in views {    
    if let cell = v as? BaseCell {
        cell.configure(viewModel)
    }
 }
```

the caveat is that your concrete cells need to cast the view model type:

```
func configure<T : BaseViewModel>(viewmodel: T) {
    if let vm = viewmodel as SomeCellViewModelInterface {
        vm.doSomething()
    }
}
```

which is better but still not ideal because the cast still needs to happen in the cell.